# Communicating with azure container using server-less function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-container-service

I have created a python serverless function in azure that gets executed when a new file is uploaded to azure blob (BlobTrigger). The function extracts certain properties of the file and saves it in the DB. As the next step, I want this function copy and process the same file inside a container instance running in ACS. The result of processing should be returned back to the same azure function. 
This is a hypothetical architecture that I am currently brainstorming on. I wanted to know if this is feasible. Can you provide me some pointers on how I can achieve this. 
I dont see any ContainerTrigger kind of functionality that can allow me to trigger the container and process my next steps. 
I have tried utilizing the code examples mentioned here but they have are not really performing the tasks that I need: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aci-docs-sample-python/blob/master/src/aci_docs_sample.py

Comment: Maybe you can try to mount a persist the volume in the Container with Azure File Share. Then you can do any action you want with the files inside the File Share.

Comment: can you explain bit more what exactly are you trying to achieve. why do you want to use containers specifically when you are doing same task in az function.

Comment: @Imran I am trying to scan the blob file through an open source anti-virus called ClamAV. I have deployed clamAV as a docker container and want my fuction to access the container, initiate a scan and then get back the result. I also tried setting up clamAV as a serverless function but for some reason, it is not working. So I moved to docker container.

Comment: @CharlesXu That sounds interesting. Can I also return a response to my function from within the container once the action is complete?

Comment: You can execute the command inside the ACI to achieve it or set it as a service to trigger if the action is complete. These are advice because of no experience with Azure Function.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments above you can consider.

**Azure Container Instance**

Deploy your container in ACI (Azure Container Instance) and expose HTTP end point from container , just like any web url. Trigger Azure Function using blob storage trigger and then pass your blob file URL to the exposed http end point to your container. Process the file there and return the response back to azure function just like normal http request/response.

You can completely bypass azure function and can trigger your ACI (container instance) using logic apps , process the file and directly save in database.

When you are using Azure function make sure this is short lived process since Azure function will exit after certain time (default 5 mins). For long processing you may have to consider azure durable functions.

Following url can help you understand better. 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aci-event-driven-worker-queue